# Setting date format for particular string format in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to set NSDateFormatter for the below string:

```
   2012-12-18T09:05:24.000Z
```

It's the output of S3Object Summary lastmodifed object. What is the format I have to set it to if I need to change the display format?Any idea?

Comment: In which style or format you want your date?  Check NSDateFormatter and google, SO, You will find thousands of codes to produce same date as you want....

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *stringe = @"2010-06-21T20:06:36+00:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];

NSDate *reqDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:reqDate]);
```

Now you will get the date in NSDate object so you can change that date to as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

For 2012-12-18T09:05:24.000Z

The format string is
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'